# TypeError: string indices must be integers python shahid

Tags: python, class, oop, typeerror

`    class Auth:
def **init**(self):
self.users = {}

```
def register(self, username, email, password):
    if username in self.users:
        print("Username Already Exists")
    elif email in [u["email"] for u in self.users]:
        print("Email Already Exists")
    else:
        self.users[username] = {"email" : email,"password" : password}
        print("Account created SuccessFully")
        
def login(self, email, password):
    for username, user_info in self.users.items():
        if user_info["email"] != email:
            print("Email Address Not Found")
        elif user_info["password"] != password:
            print("Incorrect Password")
        else:
            print("Login Successfull ✅")
            print("Welcome Back!")
            print(f"Hello Mr.{username}")
            print(f"Your Email Address Is {email}")
```

user = Auth()    `

first time i tried the following code
   `user.register("Shahid Amin","aminShahid573@gmail.com","1234")`

Dear [Developer/Programmer],

As you might be aware, I was trying to register a user using the code block below:
   `user.register("Zeeshan Ali","HteZahid@gmail.com","12345")`

However, upon running the code, I received the following error message:

````
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_19712\2272879716.py in <module>
----> 1 user.register("Zeeshan Ali","HteZahid@gmail.com","12345")

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_19712\3787510597.py in register(self, username, email, password)
      6         if username in self.users:
      7             print("Username Already Exists")
----> 8         elif email in [u["email"] for u in self.users]:
      9             print("Email Already Exists")
     10         else:

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_19712\3787510597.py in <listcomp>(.0)
      6         if username in self.users:
      7             print("Username Already Exists")
----> 8         elif email in [u["email"] for u in self.users]:
      9             print("Email Already Exists")
     10         else:

TypeError: string indices must be integers    ```


how can i solve this 



Here, self.users is likely a list of dictionaries, and the code is trying to access the value associated with the "email" key for each dictionary in the list. However, the error message suggests that user is actually a string, which cannot be used as an index for a dictionary.Based on my understanding, this line of code is trying to search for the email in a list of users. However, it appears that the "user" object is being treated as a string instead of a dictionary, which is resulting in the error.

I would greatly appreciate it if you could take a look at this error and provide me with guidance on how to resolve it. I believe that a simple modification to the code block could resolve the issue, but I am not certain about the exact solution.

Thank you very much for your time and consideration. I look forward to hearing from you soon.
````

Comment: sorry for mistake ```class Auth: def init(self): self.users = {} ``` is ```  def __init__(self): self.users = {} ```

Comment: `for u in self.users`: If `self.users` is a dict, then `u` is a key of that dict. In that case `u["email"]` doesn't make sense.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

`self.users` is a dictionary and `u["email"]` doesn't work because u is the key of that dict.